# Relation between upper (or lower) riemann sums based on norm.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I can prove that if $Q$ is a refinement of $P$, ie $P\subseteq Q$ then $L(P,f)≤ L(Q,f)$ and $U(Q,f)≤ U(P,f)$.

An interesting thing to note here is that $P \subseteq Q \implies ||Q||<||P||$ but the converse is not true.

However, I'm wondering whether the following implication holds:

If $||P_1|| < ||P_2||$ then $L(P_2,f)≤L(P_1,f)$ and $U(P_1,f)≤U(P_2,f)$.

Intuitively, I think it should hold as $P_1$ is in some sense *finer* than $P_2$ but I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously because the definition of norm as maximum of the lengths of the subintervals doesn't seem easy to use. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication is false. The trick is that if your function is constant on some interval then any partition of the interval where the function is constant will give the same Riemann sum and we can therefore "trick" the norm. So for instance let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&0 \leq x\leq 1 \\
1,& 1\leq x\leq 2.\end{cases}$$
Take $P_{2} = \{0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 2\}$ and $P_{1}=\{0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2\}$ then $\|P_{1}\|=1/2<1=\|P_{2}\|$ but $L(P_{1}, f)< L(P_{2}, f)$ since $P_{2}$ is a refinement of $P_{1}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Except your $P_2$ is **not** a refinement of $P_1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It is a refinement when restricted to $[0,1]$ (by abuse of terminology)- It is of course not a refinement on $[0,2]$ but the terminology seemed appropriate. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Your $P_j$ are not even _partitions_ of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If you intersect with $[0,1]$ they are partitions of $[0,1]$ which is what I mean by "$P_{2}$ is a refinement of $P_{1}$ on $[0,1]$".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich He means $P_2$ contains all the points of $P_1$ in the interval $[0,1]$. For $[1,2]$, $P_2$ doesn't contain all the points of $P_1$ but it doesn't matter since the function is constant there. So the contribution to their corresponding lower sums by both the partitions is same on $[1,2]$. The inequality happens because of what happens on $[0,1]$. It was abuse of terminology but I think it's clear what he meant.